# Правильно ли использованы «не» и запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, частица

В книге встретила такое предложение: *Не волков, не темноты за дверьми, нет.*
Правильно ли здесь использованы "не" и запятая перед "нет"?
Если да, то почему? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Тут нужен контекст. А он таков ([Джон Толкин. Властелин колец](https://booksdaily.club/fantastika-i-fjentezi/geroicheskaja-fantastika/page-123-11671-dzhon-tolkin-vlastelin-kolec.html)):

> — Не дай ему убежать, — предостерег Боромир. — Похоже, он нам еще понадобится, если нас не съедят волки. Пропади оно пропадом, это гнилое болото!
> <...>
> — Зачем ты так, Боромир? — вздрогнул Фродо. — Мне тоже не нравится это место, но я его еще и боюсь, а почему — сам не знаю. **Не волков, не темноты за дверьми, нет.** Тут что–то другое. Наверное, я этого озера боюсь. Лучше оставим его в покое!

Пунктуация в указанном предложении правильная.
Это [неполное предложение](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/722-26_nepolnye_predlozheniya.html), в котором отсутствуют и подлежащее, и сказуемое. Они с легкостью восстанавливаются из предыдущего контекста.
*[Я боюсь] Не волков, не темноты за дверьми, нет.*

[Нет](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mas/34559/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82) — это отрицательная частица; употребляется с последующим объяснением или уточнением отрицания.
Такое объяснение имеется в следующем предложении:
*Не волков, не темноты за дверьми, нет. Тут что–то другое.*

Частица [***не***](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B5&all=x) также использована верно ("выражает полное отрицание того, что обозначает слово или сочетание, перед которым она стоит").

*― Парацельс, **я боюсь не людей**, но стремительно уходящего от нас времени* (Аркадий Вайнер, Георгий Вайнер. Лекарство против страха).

Answer (score 3):

Говорят, что переводов книги Джона Толкина "Властелин колец" на русский язык много и даже выбирают лучший.

**А как его выбрать?** Вот мнение: "Вообще любой перевод — это в каком-то смысле соавторство. Понятно, что нельзя ограничивать перевод только сохранением буквы произведения. Есть дух произведения, есть язык, есть символизм и т.д."

Но попробуем оценить перевод **одного фрагмента**.

*Мне тоже не нравится это место, но я **его** еще и боюсь, а почему — сам не знаю. **Не волков, не темноты за дверьми, нет.** Тут что–то другое. Наверное, я этого озера боюсь. Лучше оставим его в покое!*

Русскому читателю **трудно сразу понять** смысл предложения. После местоимения "его" (места) следует совершенно неясный переход  к перечислению (не волков, не темноты за дверьми, нет).

**В этом есть вина переводчика?** Наверное, да. А если что-то изменить, чтобы смысл был ясен, например:

*Мне тоже не нравится это место, но я его еще и боюсь, а почему — сам не знаю. **Но боюсь** не волков, не темноты за дверьми, нет. Тут что–то другое. Наверное, я этого озера боюсь. Лучше оставим его в покое!*

Интересно, такие "вольности" допустимы? Не думаю, что они как-то искажают текст или влияют на дух произведения. Скорее всего, нам просто предложен дословный перевод английского варианта.

Comment: Всё там ясно. –

Comment: Догадаться вполне можно. Конечно, прочитать надо раза три, не без этого. Стилистика вполне в вашем вкусе))

Comment: Мне одного раза хватило. Там всё стандартно.

Comment: А вот автору вопроса  почему-то не хватило одного раза, да и пояснение смысла  в ответе занимает много места, учитывая русские варианты отрицания (выбор НЕ/НИ, НЕТ).  Стандартная и понятная логическая связь прерывается ВСТАВКОЙ:  "Мне тоже не нравится это место, но я его еще и боюсь, а почему — сам не знаю. (Но боюсь не волков, не темноты за дверьми, нет. Тут что–то другое.) Наверное, я этого озера боюсь".  А всего-то и надо было одно слово дописать (боюсь), чтобы народ не  мучился и ребусы не разгадывал.  Кстати, за вопрос постаили 4 голоса, это о чем-то говорит?

Comment: Хватило одного раза. Вопрос о "не"/"ни", а не о смысле. Если не видеть то, что до этого, то вообще не понятно. Можно такой контекст придумать, что "ни" подойдёт. Наверно, лайки с этим связаны.

Comment: По вопросу видно, что автор не понимает именно смысл, если уж про запятую спрашивает.  И другие, возможно, не понимают. А у вас свои фантазии, как всегда. (Кстати, с Новым годом вас).  Надо, пожалуй,  еще один лайк поставить для убедительности и правомерности вопроса.

Comment: Вас тоже с Новым годом. Ну ладно, раз про запятую. Чего это у меня всегда свои фантазии? Хотя стоп, можно и так понять: *Ни волков, ни темноты за дверьми нет.*

Comment: Может, и так.  Я по переводчику два раза набрала текст.  Интересно, что запятая осталась, а частицы поменялись.  I don't like this place either, but I'm also afraid of it, and I don't know why. No wolves, no darkness behind the doors, no. There's something else here. I guess I'm afraid of this lake.  Мне тоже не нравится это место, но я также боюсь его, и я не знаю почему. Ни волков, ни тьмы за дверями, нет. Здесь есть что-то еще. Наверное, я боюсь этого озера.

Comment: Ну так да, оно так должно переводиться, а если "не", то "not", но тогда "no" непонятно.

Comment: Этого я точно не знаю, там свои тонкости, наверное. Надо у знатоков спросить. Кто у нас английский хорошо  знает.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com

Comment: И что? Своими словами можно? КАкое у них там правило для not и no. Да еще неизвестно, что было в оригинале. Ну ладно, спасибо, закрыли тему.

Comment: Там можно задать вопрос. Просто нажимаете "Join this community".